# Как в коде сделать чтоб при нажатии + в верхней лабель записывался результат?

Tags: c++-cli

Пишу свой калькулятор для задания с помощью winforms

```
private: System::Void button_plus_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    math_action('+');
}
       private: System::Void math_action(Char action) {
           this->first_num = this->result_lab2->Text;
           this->user_action = action;
           this->result_lab2->Text="0";
вот кусочек кода у меня есть два лабеля вот скрин - [![Два лабеля][1]][1]
```

вот картинка https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX6QX.png Хотел сделать так чтоб в верхней лабель записывался результат после любой операции допустим пишем  число 22 нажимаем плюс и как в виндовом калькуляторе писало вверху 22+

Comment: [тыц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1570504/winforms-c-Полное-отсутствие-понимания-и-внятного-руководства#comment2830407_1570504)

Comment: Спасибо, но я ведь учусь,да я понимаю что это лишь обертка я реализовал более менее то что хотел, то, но не до конца мало того что вы просто указали статью, но не смогли помочь жалко, честно говоря, обидно за такой классный форму где много умных людей не смогли помочь а с какого то жалкого ответы майл.ру более понятно объяснили

Comment: и по поводу IDE не согласен ведь удобно писать в visual studio code

Comment: VS и VS Code - две совершенно разные IDE.